# Trying to retrieve the data from text box

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

[image]

HTML is as shown above,

I just uploaded the `excel` from where data will get populated in the text field, from which I need to retrieve the data and compare, I have used `getText()` method, but unable to retrieve the data.

[image]

Above shown is a piece of code I have tried, there are two matching nodes hence using the above format

[image]

Above shown is the field from which I want to retrieve the data

[image]

This is the output it is returning.

Comment: When are you trying to retrieve the value? Before entering or after entering it in the text field?

Verify the xpath you used is pointing to exact that field only and not to any other field.

Comment: when you type something on the input where is the text getting stored in the element locator. After uploading search for that text in the DOM and see under which element the text is coming up. Also try using getAttribute("textContent") instead of getText()

Comment: Thanks PDHide getAttribute("value") solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be trying to retrieve the value of the field, as text entered into one is not stored in "text".

Give this a try instead of .getText():

```
.getAttribute("value")
```